What dimensions should a can have?
the question
What dimensions should a can have, in the conditions
to a given filling volume, noted with $V$, if a percentage $p$ of the material
used is lost during the making of the bottom and lid of the box because of
the shape of the cutout and the shape of the initial material, and the manufacturer wants to
use a minimum amount of material? (The shape of the box is a cylinder
right circular).
my idea
We know that the volume of a cylinder right circular is $V=h\pi R^2$, where h is its height and R is the radius of the base
Also, the material used to make the lateral surface is the same, without lost material, which means that it can be calculated as $h 2\pi R$.
The area of the lid and the bottom can be expressed as $2\pi R^2$, but we have to mention this after we eliminate that p percentage.
I don't know what to do next.

Do you know how to find the minimum of a continuous function, using differential calculus?

@MJD Not really, but can you try writing an answer and I will try to understand it?

If not calculus, what tools you have at your disposal?

@JyrkiLahtonen I thought that we can use the formulas I wrote in my idea and process them ....

@m-stgt Sorry... i will edit it

Why are people voting to close my post? Please tell me so I can correct my mistake!

Use the AM-GM inequality to get
$$2\pi hR + 2t\pi R^2 = \pi h R + \pi h R + 2t\pi R^2 \ge 3\pi(2th^2 R^4)^{1/3} = 3 \sqrt[3]{2\pi t V^2}$$
where $t = 1/(1-(p/100))$. Equality holds exactly when $hR = hR = 2tR^2$, ie $h = 2tR$, given $V \ne 0 \implies R \ne 0$.
At the minimum, you can plug in $h = 2tR$ into $V = \pi h R^2$ and solve to get $R = \sqrt[3]{V/2\pi t}$ and $h = \sqrt[3]{4t^2V/\pi}$.

Thank you for your answer! But how does your answer respond the question of the problem if we need to find h and R and you express h using R

@ronno -- Sorry, my tired eyes muddled $+$ and $-$. Nonetheless, multiply with $(1+p)$ or $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-p}$ is not exactly the same ($p$ is the percentage, so $1+3\text{%}=1.03$)

@m-stgt I agree that they are not the same and I stand by what I've written

@ronno -- There seems no error in the calculation, only in the ansatz. When "a percentage p of the material used is lost during the making of the bottom and lid", must I utilise $(1+p)$ material to get $100$% of it for the bottoms and the lid -- or, because only $(1-p)$ will make it to become bottoms and lids, deploy $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-p}$ sheet metal for the two ends of the can?

First: the "simple" way would be, in the formula for the total surface (including percentage $p$ waste for lid and bottom)
$$h\cdot 2\pi R + 2\pi R^2(1+p)\tag{1}$$
to replace either $h$ or $R$ with the ratio from the formula for the volume
$$V=h\pi R^2\tag{2}$$
so for example
$$h=\frac{V}{\pi R^2}\tag{2.1}$$
Substituted $h$ in $(1)$ gets
$$\frac{2\left((1+p)\pi R^3+V\right)}{R}\tag{1.1}$$
And now? I would prepare a diagram, but that's only possible when replacing $V$ and $p$ with hypothetical figures. Thinking of canned tomato soup I'd suggest to fix volume at $V=500\ {cm}^3$ and $p=3$%, the resulting plot shows a minimum surface with $R$ between $4\ ..\ 4.5\ cm$.

So far the simple way which at least gives an approach of a realistic $R$ me think.
Second: the canonical way.
To find the minimum of the graph shown above, derive $(1.1)$ to $R$
$$\frac{2\left((1+p)2\pi R^3-V\right)}{R^2}\tag{3}$$
A local minimum or maximum is, where this derivative is $0$. Solved for $R$ results
$$R=\sqrt[\displaystyle 3]{\frac{V}{(1+p)2\pi}}\tag{3.1}$$
This checked with the a. m. figures you get $R\approx 4.26\ cm$ -- same as in the diagram.

Note that the loss given by $p$ only occurs with the top and bottom

@ronno -- TY, updated my answer accordingly.

@m-stgt I still don't understand the final answer for the first way of solving...we have to find the dimension of the can...Shouldn't we use AM-GM as in the comment below?

@IONELABUCIU -- my first way of solving is a very simplistic approach of a numeric solution (which may be enhanced by iterative algorithms). It has nothing to do with AM-GM. With $R$ determied precisely enough, you find $h$ with equation $(2.1)$.
